# Does React compares whole tree on every change?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say we have this structure:

```
export const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <Child />
  )
}

const Child = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => {setState(state + 1)}}>{state}</button>
      <GrandChild />
    </>
  )
}

const GrandChild = () => {
  return (
    <div>Hello</div>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Parent />);
```

React will build a new UI tree (VDOM) when I click the button in Child, and compare it with the previous one to make changes in DOM. In this particular case, Child and GrandChild will be re-rendered and changes in DOM would be only text inside the button.

So, what I need to know is: will it compare whole UI trees with diffing algorithm? Or will it compare only subtrees, starting from Child?

I read both React docs: legacy and the new one. But couldn't find a direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

No, diffing the whole tree would be inefficient and possibly lead to a whole-app re-render on every update.

The relevant part of the legacy docs is [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), an an old but blog post on how it works is [here](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/diff/). There doesn't seem to be anything useful in the new docs, it looks like they removed the entire "advanced concepts" section.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I already read them.
And how diffing can cause any re-render, if it happens after re-render to calculate changes in DOM? By render I mean calling render method or its analogue in FC.

Comment: @Arseniy When you call `render` or some method that would update the UI, that doesn't go to the DOM first, it goes to the v-DOM; the diff is between the current (old) DOM and the v-dom, and then changes are batched so as to only render to the actual DOM once. And the "whole-app re-render" case would be if there was a top-down diff, because the entirety of `body` would conceptually be affected by any changes collected that way.

Comment: Well, maybe its a typo, but React never compares DOM and VDOM, it only compares old and current versions of VDOM.

Comment: @Arseniy not a typo, I was just incorrect. I need more coffee. :)